# how to find Zooming factor from mouse scrolling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, pinchzoom

- Need to zooming the page when user scrolling with ctrl + ,
- If I find the Zoom factor mean I zoom the current page with based on factor.
- For example when I am getting zoom factor 1.44. so I am converting this into 144% and doing zooming operation.
- I am searching in many ways. but I am not getting the result.
- can you please say how to find Zoom factor from mouse scrolling?
- my code is below - here I ned to find this.zoomval?

Please help me!

```
var zoomFactor = scaleFactor;
var pageViewerContainer = $('#id');
var pagecontainer = $('#id');
this._selectionNodes = window.getSelection();
if (!(this._selectionNodes.anchorOffset == 0 && this._selectionNodes.focusOffset == 0)) {
  this._maintainSelection();
}
if (isFactor) {
  this._zoomVal = this._zoomVal + zoomFactor;
}
var w = pagecontainer.width();
var h = pagecontainer.height();
var zoomineventvalue = { currentZoomPercentage: 0, previousZoomPercentage: 0 };
var vscrolBar = document.getElementById(this._id + '_viewerContainer');
var vscrolValue = vscrolBar.scrollTop;
var scrollValue = (vscrolValue / this._previousZoom) * this._zoomVal;
var transform = "scale(" + this._zoomVal + "," + this._zoomVal + ")";
for (var i = 1; i <= this._totalPages; i++) {
  var leftpos = (this.element.width() - this._pageSize[i - 1].PageWidth * this._zoomVal) / 2;
  if (leftpos < 0 || this._fitType=="fitToWidth")
    leftpos = 5;
  var canvas = document.getElementById('pagecanvas_' + i);
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageHeight * this._zoomVal;
  canvas.width = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageWidth * this._zoomVal;
  canvas.style.height = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageHeight * this._zoomVal + 'px';
  canvas.style.width = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageWidth * this._zoomVal + 'px';
  var height = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageHeight * this._zoomVal;
  var width = this._pageSize[i - 1].PageWidth * this._zoomVal;
  canvas.style.width = width + "px";
  canvas.style.height = height + "px";
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
  var pagediv = $('#' + this._id + 'pageDiv_' + i);
  pagediv[0].style.top = this._pageLocation[i] * this._zoomVal + "px";
  pagediv[0].style.left = leftpos + "px";

  //Hyperlink canvas

  var hyperlinklayer = document.getElementById('selectioncanvas_' + i);
  hyperlinklayer.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
  hyperlinklayer.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
  hyperlinklayer.style.position = 'absolute';
  hyperlinklayer.style.left = 0;
  hyperlinklayer.style.top = 0;
  hyperlinklayer.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  hyperlinklayer.style.opacity = '0.2';
  hyperlinklayer.style.zIndex = '2';

  if (!this._isAutoZoom) {
    //resizing the loding indicator of the page
    $('#').css({ 'display': 'block', 'height': canvas.height + 'px', 'width': canvas.width + 'px','left':'0px','top':'0px' });
    var loadingindicator = document.getElementById(this._id + 'pageDiv_' + i + '_WaitingPopup');
    var spanDiv = loadingindicator.childNodes[0];
    spanDiv.style.top = (canvas.height - spanDiv.clientHeight) / 2 + 'px';
  }
}
if (this._renderedCanvasList)
  this._renderedCanvasList.length = 0;
if (this._zoomVal < 1)
  pageViewerContainer.css({ '-ms-scroll-limit-y-max': (this._cummulativeHeight * this._zoomVal) - this.element.height() + 50 + "px" 
});
else {
  pageViewerContainer.css({ '-ms-scroll-limit-y-max': "" });
}
vscrolBar.scrollTop = scrollValue;
this._eventpreviouszoomvalue = this._preZoomVal;
this._eventzoomvalue = this._zoomVal;
this._preZoomVal = this._zoomVal;
this._previousZoom = this._zoomVal;
zoomineventvalue.previousZoomPercentage = Math.round(this._eventpreviouszoomvalue * 100);
zoomineventvalue.currentZoomPercentage = Math.round(this._eventzoomvalue * 100);
this._raiseClientEvent("zoomChange", zoomineventvalue);
this.zoomPercentage = Math.round(this._zoomVal * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the zooming factor (relative to the first document opening, that can be zoomed as well) by saving the window width right after opening and then binding a window resize event and checking the ratio between the original size and the actual one.

This is an HTML example:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Test Zoom</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>
      Original Document Width: <span id="originaldocumentwidth"></span>
      </h2>

       <h2>
        New Document Width: <span id="newdocumentwidth"></span>
      </h2>

       <h2>
        Zoom Factor: <span id="zoomratio"></span>
      </h2>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var originaldocumentwidth = $(document).width();
            var newdocumentwidth = $(document).width();
            var zoomratio = originaldocumentwidth / newdocumentwidth;

            function updateZoom() {
                newdocumentwidth = $(document).width();
                zoomratio = originaldocumentwidth / newdocumentwidth;

                $('#originaldocumentwidth').html(originaldocumentwidth);
                $('#newdocumentwidth').html(newdocumentwidth);
                $('#zoomratio').html(zoomratio);
            }
            $(window).resize(function() {
                updateZoom();
            });
            updateZoom();
        });
      </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action on this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nemoneminis/cLj0f9mm/).